# SQL Server query to update and calculate a field at the same time

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

My query is as follows:

I have a table Named CALLS as given below:

```
CALL_NUMBER   PART_NUMBER  QTY  ARRIVAL_DATE
    A1            XXX1      5     
    B2            YYY2      25     
    C3            ZZZ3      120
    D4            ZZZ3      80
    E5            ZZZ3      25
```

And another table SHIPPING as given below:

```
PART_NUMBER   QTY    SHIP_DATE   ARRIVAL_DATE
XXX1          100      26-Dec      28-Dec
YYY2            5      29-Dec       6-Jan
ZZZ3          200      29-Dec      18-Jan
```

Now my aim is to put in an arrival date in the calls table based on if the qty required is satisfied by the quantity shipped. If not then, no date should be given in the CALLS table.

I thought the update query below may work:

```
UPDATE CALLS 
SET ARRIVAL_DATE = s.ARRIVAL_DATE
FROM
(
  SELECT PART_NUMBER,QTY,ARRIVAL_DATE 
  FROM SHIPPING
)s
WHERE PART_NUMBER = s.PART_NUMBER
AND QTY < s.QTY
```

But then how do I subtract the assigned quantities from the remining ones in SHIPPING?

Kindly help me out with this one.

Comment: You cannot update two different tables at the same time in SQL Server. Your best option is to place two separate update statements inside a single transaction.

Comment: Why not just sum the qty and return the max(arrival_date) from your inline view?  but shipping should have some sort of reference to call_number for this to work.  Otherwise how do I know that XX1 ties to call A1 and we overshipped by 95?

Comment: Hello Giorgos. I think the transaction idea may work. SO baically I run the above update with another update query to subtract the quantity from shipping. This will work line by line I presume?

Comment: Thanks for your answer xQbert. THe problem is the fields in the shipping table cannot be mapped directly to each call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if wrong. You want to update ARRIVAL_DATE column from Calls table and if the ARRIVAL_DATE column updates then at the same time you want to reduce its QTY value from SHIPPING table.

If yes then this can only be done by looping through each rows in calls table and updating the shipping table after. I have used while loop instead of cursors as mentioned below :

```
declare @i int = (select count(*) from calls)
declare @j int = 0
declare @t table
(part_number varchar(10),qty int)


while @j <= @i
begin
update a
set a.arrival_date = b.arrival_date
output inserted.part_number,inserted.qty into @t
from
(select *,row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as rn
from calls
) as a
inner join shipping as b
on a.part_number = b.part_number
where a.qty < = b.qty and a.rn = (case when @j = 0 then 1 else @j end)

update a
set a.qty = a.qty - b.qty
from shipping as a
inner join @t as b
on a.part_number = b.part_number

delete from @t
set @j = @j + 1
end
```

Comment: Hello Sam, you are spot on with your understanding of the problem. I will try this out in a test environment and get back to you with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just have to subtract the QTY in CALLS from the QTY in SHIPPING?
(updated 12/16 with the following as the original update didn't lend itself well to what I'm proposing...take a look)

```
UPDATE CALLS 
  SET C.PART_NUMBER = S.PART_NUMBER,
     C.QTY = SUM(C.QTY - S.QTY),
      C.ARRIVAL_DATE = S.ARRIVAL_DATE 
  FROM SHIPPING S JOIN CALLS C ON C.PART_NUMBER = S.PART_NUMBER
  WHERE C.QTY < S.QTY
```

Since you are only updating the ones with enough quantities in CALLS then all that satisfy updating the ARRIVAL_DATE field - unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Please, as always with SQL.. test this first somewhere before using on live data. :)

Comment: Hello Sergio, will this work on the case in my data for ZZZ3 wherein first two instances will get ETA but last wont because the stock shipped is depleted?

Comment: this won't update the amount you have in SHIPPING though the way it is. Did you want that to  happen too?

Comment: oh no I dont want it to be updated in SHIPPING. I just want the query to know when to stop updating ETA in calls.

Comment: you have to update the SHIPPING table to reflect anything you're holding for the ones in the CALLS table, no?

Comment: Hello Sergio, i tested the above, it says an aggregate should not appear in an UPDATE statement,

Comment: sorry, didn't see this until this morning.